# Impressão de atributos do tipo boolean em java

Tags: java, booleano

Bom dia! Estou começando agora no java e tenho a seguinte dúvida:
"Por que o atribulo Mensalidade do tipo boolean não aparece para eu exibir o resultado informado?" 
Segue abaixo a imagem das opções que aparecem quando eu pressiono CTRL+Barra de Espaço.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Onde está sendo declarada essa class Aluno?

Comment: Se vc está utilizando a IDE para gerar o código da classe Aluno, é bastante possível que o nome do método tenha sido gerado como isMensalidade().

Comment: @PauloR.F.Amorim não entendi sua pergunta, mais apenas criei a classe Aluno e utilizei ela no main.

Comment: Queria ver o arquivo Aluno.java que aparece ao lado

Comment: Inseri na pergunta, o print da classe Aluno.

Comment: De preferencia coloque o código ao invés de imagem, isso facilita para quem estiver te ajudando.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se você utilizou o *genereate get and set* do eclipse ele coloca atributos do tipo boolean como *`isMensalidade()`*

Comment: Realmente, como eu havia utilizado o generate getters ans setters do eclipse ele colocou o atributo como isMensalidade. Eu alterei para getMensalidade e funcionou corretamente. 
Obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score 1):

Em situações como essa, você deve ir na classe e verificar se o método que deseja foi declarado.

Quando o intellisense não mostra o método/atributo, significa que ou o método/atributo não existe ou a classe que está tentando acessá-lo não tem permissão para isso. Por exemplo, o método poderia estar como `private`, nesse caso, mesmo se o método existisse você também não iria conseguir enxergá-lo pelo intellisense.

Como já mencionado na resposta https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/278954/7521, se você gerou o código pela IDE, provavelmente o método está com o nome `isMensalidade()`. As IDEs normalmente inserem código seguindo o padrão da linguagem, no caso do Java, atributos booleanos seguem esse padrão de métodos de acesso:

```
private boolean hidden;

public void setHidden(boolean hidden) {
    this.hidden = hidden;
}

public boolean isHidden() {
    return this.hidden;
}
```